Can women uncover some area above their wrists in public while for e.g. working with chemicals in a chemistry lab, or during a surgery(as a surgeon)?
This question only pertains to the specific cases mentioned above as we all know that a woman has to cover her arms till her wrists as these areas are the part of sitr. The question has been asked since the Muslimah got no choice as the chemicals interfering with the sleeves may cause her harm ,and during the surgery, sleeves might be quite a big risk when operating on a human body. Plus, the Muslimah covers her arms till her wrists as soon as her work is done.(Answers as per the Hanafi Fiqh would be highly appreciated)

There's likely no problem w.r.t. surgery as it involves dealing with human life. Whatever action the process requires the surgeon to do, even if it is haram to any extent, and one is sure that there is no lesser haram or halal alternative available for it at the moment, then they can do it. Let's wait for answers insha Allah. This is a good, focused question so I hope this gets an answer. It does require some editing that I will do later on insha Allah.

Jazak Allahu Khairan Kaseera
